# Doctrine 2 entities with one to many relations

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to fetch an annotation with an one to many relation but as soon as I use a join I will end up with the following data:

```
entities\Topic
    id    = 1            // integer
    title = "example"    // string
    comments             // entities\Comment = oneToMany
        id   = 1                    // integer
        comment = "first comment"   // string
        topic                       // entities\Topic = manyToOne
            id    = 1 // again..
            title = "example"
```

Why does doctrine fetch the the manyToOne relation inside comments when I join on the topics comments? This is my query:

```
$this->em->createQueryBuilder()
         ->from('Entities\Topic', 't')
         ->select("t, c")
         ->leftjoin("t.comments", 'c')
         ->where('t.id = :id')
         ->setParameter('id', 1)
         ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Shouldn't the topic property be null or at least an empty arrayCollection?

Another thing:

Why do I get a PersistentCollection back as comments when I specify that comments is an arrayCollection? Do I always need to use unwrap on the PersistentCollection before I can loop through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first bit - it's likely populating the topic because it already has the data.  Were the data not already on-hand, you'd likely have a proxy entity there.  It would never be null, because null would be wrong (the comment does have a topic).

As for ArrayCollection/PersistentCollection, you can safely ignore the distinction.  I don't know the implementation details, but basically, the EM gives back stuff in PersistentCollections, which I assume play a role in managing the entities in the collection.  If you're creating the collection, you use ArrayCollection.  Sorry I can't be more specific here, but the bottom line is, you should probably just think about any PersistentCollections you get from the EM as just "a collection"

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the population of the children's child? I'm sending the data back to the client side so I need to keep it as minimalistic as possible without losing flexibility.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way, to be honest.  I typically write a toArray() method for any entity I want to serialize, so I can control the depth of the tree that I serialize and send to the client.